# Creating an extension method for a generic type interface

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I want to restrict my extension method but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

1. No control can find my extension method.
2. Any control can find my extension method. But I don't want it to be found by those who don't have the `IMyProp` interface.

How can I hide/restrict my extension method from those classes that don't implement the `IMyProp` interface?

**Additional explanation:**
I have multiple classes inherited by `MyPropBase`.
eg: `MyPropButton`, `MyPropTextBox`..
I have set it to automatically apply different contents by the `MyPropBase` class even though they are different classes.
In this way, my extension method can do the same for all different classes, and it works for all different classes.

```
public interface IMyProp<T> where T : MyPropBase
{
    T MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

1. 

```
public static void DoSomething<T>(this T @this) where T : Control, IMyProp<MyPropBase>
{
    //
}
private MyButton CreateMyButton()
{
    MyButton btn = new();
    btn.DoSomething(); //Error code: CS0311
    return btn;
}
```

2. 

```
public static void DoSomething<T1,T2>(this T1 @this, T2 myProp) where T1 : Control, IMyProp<T2> where T2 : MyPropBase
{
    //
}
private MyButton CreateMyButton()
{
    MyButton btn = new();
    btn.DoSomething(btn.MyProp);
    return btn;

    //Button btn = new();
    //btn.DoSomething(btn.MyProp); //Error code: CS1061
    //return btn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve. My guess is that you would like to reuse some code and only expose the functionality to instances that have the type in the `this` parameter of the extension. This is what I cooked up:

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void DoSomething(this MyPropBase prop)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public interface IMyProp<T>
        where T : MyPropBase
    {
        T MyProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyProp01 : MyPropBase, IMyProp<MyPropBase>
    {
        public MyPropBase MyProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyPropBase
    {

    }
}
```

Because the extension method accepts `MyPropBase` as `this`, it will only be visible to types that inherit `MyPropBase`.

```
var prop01 = new MyProp01();

prop01.DoSomething();
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: AFAIK extension method of the base class will not be visible to the derived class.

Comment: Runtime polymorphism should take care of that problem.

Comment: No, not true. Derived classes also see the extension method.

Comment: When you call DoSomething on `MyPropBase`, it will call an override of the DoSomething method in the derived class, if one exists.

Comment: One must exist. The interface enforces that.

Comment: `MyPropBase` could also be an `abstract` class with the `MyProp` as a `public abstract`. Then you don't need the `interface` and the MyProp would have to be implemented in deriving classes.

Comment: My last remark only works in my example. The OP wants to inherit from `Control`. You can only inherit 1 type so the `interface` is still needed I quess.

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine. Right now it's fine as I don't inherit from a different class, but if it were inherited from a different class. For example:```MyProp01``` is ```MyButton```. ```MyButton```; It is already inherited by ```System.Windows.Forms.Button```. In this case I cannot inherit from ```MyPropBase```.

Comment: @Emre If you can't inherit you can wrap it. Inject you object in the constructor. But it would need a lot of code to get that working as expected. No polymorphism can be used then. Until C# allows for multiple types to be inherited we have to cope with what we got and it's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can check the type of the object in your extension method and throw an exception if the object is not assignable from the Interface.
This method will still allow all the controls to find the extension method but there will be a runtime exception for the ones that don't implement the interface.

I am building the code below based on @Paul's answer

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void DoSomething(this MyPropBase prop)
        {
            // if (prop is IMyProp<MyPropBase>) // Cleaner way uing is keyword
            if (typeof(IMyProp<MyPropBase>).IsAssignableFrom(prop.GetType()))
            {
                // Do work
                // This code block will only be executed from class that implement the interface IMyProp
            }
            else
            {
                throw new MethodAccessException("Method not supported");
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IMyProp<T> where T : MyPropBase
    {
        T MyProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyPropBase
    { }

    public class MyPropButton : MyPropBase, IMyProp<MyPropBase>
    {
        public MyPropBase MyProp { get; set; }
    }

    // Test the logic
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var test2 = new MyPropButton();
            test2.DoSomething();

            var test = new MyPropBase();
            test.DoSomething();// Exception is thrown
        }
    }
}
```